# How can I make widgets adjust their size to look the same on every device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I was wondering how to make my interface's TextViews, ImageViews, Margins, etc... look the same on all devices no matter if I'm using it on a phone or a tablet. I was told that using fragments would help, but I don't seem to understand. Sorry for the babyish question...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, exactly.  Different devices have different sizes, aspect ratios, etc....it's not possible to have everything be exactly the same size with the same margins.  What do you mean by "look the same"?

Comment: If I have a TextView that has a certain size on a small phone, it should appear the same way on a tablet, meaning that it has to get bigger and stabilize its size as screen size increase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraint layout and set the widget's height and width according to the screen's width and height. Or you can have different layout files for diffrent screen densities.

Comment: For API 26 or higher you can also use Autosizing TextViews.
Have a look : [Autosizing Textviews android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)